# await inside or outside expect?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, jasmine

What's difference between:

```
it('should blabla', async () => {
    await expect(callThatReturnsAPromise()).toBe(false);
});
```

and:

```
it('should blabla', async () => {
    expect(await callThatReturnsAPromise()).toBe(false);
});
```

So, await outside or inside the expect function?

And what if the call inside toBe also returns a promise, which version should I use?

```
it('should blabla', async () => {
    await expect(callThatReturnsAPromise()).toBe(callThatReturnsAPromise2());
});
```

or:

```
 it('should blabla', async () => {
     expect(await callThatReturnsAPromise()).toBe(await callThatReturnsAPromise2());
 });
```

So will await outside the expect resolves all promises or do I have to await each one of them inside the functions?

Ok, I tested with this code:

```
let a = function() {
        console.log('huba');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(42);
            }, 5000);
        });
    };

    let b = function() {
        console.log('buba');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                resolve(11);
            }, 5000);
        });
    };

    describe('test', function() {
        it('blabla', async function() {
            await expect(a()).toBe(b());
        });
    });
```

and it seems that the await outside the expect waits for promise a() and b() to be resolved. But I don't know why. Neither expect doesn't return a promise nor toBe. So why can I await outside of them?

Comment: The same as the difference between `promise() === false` and `(await promise()) === false`. One makes sense and works, the other doesn't.

Comment: Right now I guess you compare `promise1` with `promse2` which is always `false` and the promise is not awaited.

Comment: @Bergi ok, the later one makes more sense. But it doesn't answer my question why the await expect(a()).toBe(b()) waits for both promises.

Roland Starke in my last example with await expect(a()).toBe(b()) it waits for both promises. And it compares 42 with 11.

Comment: Could you verify and compare `42` with`42`? And also move the console log inside the timeout?

Comment: @GarfieldKlon Maybe `expect` knows how to compare promises - by waiting for them and comparing the result values. But I don't know the library you are using.

Comment: Ever since [v3.3.0](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/commit/2d303a6e46e5904c10d61cce007f92a8e18961d3) they did some weird things but that still doesn't explain why it works.. weird.